# Las barras no empiezan el punto de coordenadas(x) solicitado

Tags: php, mysql, chart.js

soy nuevo con chart.js y tengo datos de que deben empezar en el mes 06  o 03 del eje x (es variable dependiendo de los datos en la BD) como hago para que el data  empiece en ese punto y no en en 01 ...paso el codigo esta en PHP con las consultas a la base de datos mysql

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var data = {
    labels: [
    <?php 

    $sql = "SELECT DATE_FORMAT(Fecha_Carga,'%m') as Fechas FROM tablaunion1 where YEAR(Fecha_Carga) = '$año' Group by MONTH(Fecha_Carga)";
    $result =  mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
    while ($registros = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
    {
    ?>
        '<?php echo $registros["Fechas"] ?>',
    <?php
    }

    ?>

    ],
    datasets: [
        {
            label: "Litros consumidos",
            fillColor: "rgba(220,220,220,0.2)",
            strokeColor: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
            pointColor: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
            pointStrokeColor: "#fff",
            pointHighlightFill: "#fff",
            pointHighlightStroke: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
            data: 
            <?php 
            $sql= "SELECT  ROUND(SUM(Cantidad_Litros),2) as Litros from tablaunion1 where YEAR(Fecha_Carga) = '$año' and Patente = '$patente' Group by MONTH(Fecha_Carga)";
            $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
            ?>
            [<?php while ($registros= mysqli_fetch_array($result)){ ?><?php echo $registros["Litros"] ?>,<?php }?>]

        },
        {
            label: "Kilometros recorridos",
            fillColor: "rgba(151,187,205,0.2)",
            strokeColor: "rgba(151,187,205,1)",
            pointColor: "rgba(151,187,205,1)",
            pointStrokeColor: "#fff",
            pointHighlightFill: "#fff",
            pointHighlightStroke: "rgba(151,187,205,1)",
            data: 
            <?php 
            $sql= "SELECT ROUND(SUM(Kmrecorridos),2) as Km  FROM usitrack where YEAR(Fecha) = '$año' and Patente = '$patente' Group by MONTH(Fecha)";
            $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
            ?>
            [<?php while ($registros= mysqli_fetch_array($result)){ ?><?php echo $registros["Km"] ?>,<?php }?>]

        },
        {
        }
    ]
  };
  var pdata = [
    {
        value: 300,
        color:"#F7464A",
        highlight: "#FF5A5E",
        label: "Red"
    },
    {
        value: 50,
        color: "#46BFBD",
        highlight: "#5AD3D1",
        label: "Green"
    },
    {
        value: 100,
        color: "#FDB45C",
        highlight: "#FFC870",
        label: "Yellow"
    }
  ]

  var ctxl = $("#lineChartDemo").get(0).getContext("2d");
  var lineChart = new Chart(ctxl).Line(data);

  var ctxb = $("#barChartDemo").get(0).getContext("2d");
  var barChart = new Chart(ctxb).Bar(data);
```

Answer (score 0):

No lo he probado, pero en teoría para escalas lineales puedes cambiar el valor mínimo para que no sea 0 con [scale service](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/axes/). Espero que te sirva.

```
barChart.scaleService.updateScaleDefaults('linear', {
  ticks: { min: 2 }
});
```

Comment: En que parte del código debiera ir

Comment: después de crear el gráfico, al final de tu código, ya me dirás si funciona

Comment: No, no funciona lo inserte y no me muestra el grafico ...

Comment: Vaya,  a ver si alguien tiene otro modo